# Getting the Emp_ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In Table_A I have atrribute "Verantwortlicher". This attribute contains the last name and the first name of the person respectively i.e. "Doe John"

In Table_B I have two attributes "Lastname_NAM" and "Firstname_NAM" which of course contain lastnames and firstnames of a person respectively i.e. 
"Lastname_NAM" - Doe
"Firstname_NAM" - John

Table_A has a foreign key (Responsible_Emp_ID) which is referencing Table_B´s primary key (Emp_ID)

What I would like is to join these two tables so that beside the strig-type full name in the Table_A I also have a ID of that person (which of course comes from Table_B)

I forgot to mention that I need this data so I can FILL the values in aforeign key. Table_A is EMPTY.

I´m using T-SQL
Please help,
Thanks, D.

Comment: "I´m using T-SQL" : then don't tag a question with mysql

Comment: Maybe colleagues who know mysql can help. 
The concept is important and could solve the question.

Comment: The SQL tag is sufficient for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
--Populate TableA
INSERT INTO TableA(Responsible_Emp_ID, Verantwortlicher) 
SELECT EmpID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName
FROM TableB B

--SELECT to join the 2 tables
SELECT B.EmpID, A.Verantwortlicher
FROM TableB B
INNER JOIN TableA A
    ON B.EmpID = A.Responsible_Emp_ID

--Just make the join
SELECT C.FullName, A.EmpID FROM
(SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName
FROM TABLE B) C
INNER JOIN TableA A
    ON C.FullName = A.Verantwortlicher
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need this data so I can FILL the values in aforeign key. Table_A is EMPTY.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a script that will initially populate TableA. Hope it helps.

Comment: But how do you join two tables when the table_A is empty? I need to JOIN them using the employee names in order to get the Emp_ID from table_B 
Why are you doing insert into table_b?

Comment: Ok, that has confused me. You said that TableA was empty and you needed to populate it. It the table is empty, you will not be able to join to it. If you mean that the names are populated, but the key column is empty and you just want to make the join on name, then see the last script in the ammended answer

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
SELECT 
    B.EmpID, 
    ISNULL(A.Verantwortlicher,B.Firstname_NAM++B.Lastname_NAM) 
FROM 
    TableB B 
        LEFT JOIN TableA A 
            ON B.EmpID = A.Responsible_Emp_ID
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need this data so I can FILL the values in aforeign key. Table_A is EMPTY.